# Username as Subdomain - MAMP - Laravel 4.0

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain, laravel-4, mamp

I am working in a Laravel 4.0 project and I am new in Laravel framework. I am developing a multiple tenant application using laravel where i am going to use 'UserName' as subdomain. If a user browse their assigned subdomain, they will see the customized information and page.

For example, someone browse xyz.myapp.com, they will see the customised page which have been developed for the user's customer.

To get subdomain working , i have used the following laravel code.

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'), function()
{

    Route::get('user/{id}', function($account, $id)
    {
        return view::make('profile')
    });

});
```

however, When i have tried to visit xyz.myapp.com i am receiving following error:

```
Server not found

          Firefox can't find the server at xyz.myapp.com.
```

I guess i need to do some tricks in MAMP. I have search a lot few days for enabling subdomains dynamically in MAMP environment but i am out of luck. Please help!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this Apache2 documentation : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/mass.html to see how using URL rewriting on subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial on multiple subdomain is for Codeigniter framework, but the server configurations should be the same.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/basecamp-style-subdomains-with-codeigniter/